# Deep learning ; LSTM out-of-sample prediction

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecast

0

I am trying to do out-of-sample prediction of housing price index with deep learning LSTM.
I've practiced the code with a sample data (apt_data_sc) splitting it with 70%,30% training and test set (split_date is the break point). The below code is the part of the model that shows data and model making, and fitting process.

Then I modified the data to include empty rows for the portion to be predicted out-of-sample, and reran the model.

The problem is that the validation data for the out-of-sample model does not have any information, and the prediction on the "x_val_multi" become "nan".

Would anyone help me on this? Thank you very much for your help in advance. if needed, I can post the full code with the data.

```
past_history = 1 
future_target = 1 



x_train_multi, y_train_multi = multivariate_data(apt_data_sc, apt_data_sc[:, 0], 0,
                                                 split_date, past_history,future_target)
x_val_multi, y_val_multi = multivariate_data(apt_data_sc, apt_data_sc[:, 0],
                                             split_date, None, past_history, future_target)

model_multi = Sequential() 
model_multi.add(LSTM(60, return_sequences=True,
                    input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:])) 
model_multi.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=False,
                    activation='relu')) 
model_multi.add(Dense(y_val_multi.shape[1])) 
model_multi.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') 
model_multi.summary()

### model fitting 

TM_RMSE_10 =[]
repeats = 1
for _ in range(repeats):
        model_multi.fit(x_train_multi, y_train_multi, epochs=200,
                batch_size=1, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                validation_split=0.7, 
                validation_data=(x_val_multi, y_val_multi)) 
        TM_RMSE_10.append(np.sqrt(model_multi.evaluate(x_val_multi, y_val_multi, verbose=True)))
        TM_RMSE_10_Mean = np.mean(TM_RMSE_10, axis = 0)
        MULTI_PREDICT_train.append(model_multi.predict(x_train_multi))
        MULTI_PREDICT_test.append(model_multi.predict(x_val_multi))
```

Comment: isn't it just a regression problem? Clarify what do you mean by out of sample data with data examples.

Comment: Thank you furcifer! My data is about real estate price index of 185 time points. What I would like to predict the future value out of the 185 time points, hence the out-of-sample prediction. I modified the data to have the future (out-of-sample) time points (extra rows) with no value ("Nan").

Comment: if your validation set has no data, don't use that. Train only on the sample with values, generate more segments. Increase samples by augmentation if possible. https://github.com/hfawaz/aaltd18